# Extract value between two strings in batch using a CSV file

Tags: regex, csv, batch-file, regular-language

I have a CSV file which contains multiple columns. One of these columns is HTML content. My first step is to search for `&lt;&lt;&lt;` and replace it with <<< - secondly I'm searching for `&gt;&gt;&gt;` and replace it with >>>.

My goal is to create an array in batch. For this procedure I would like to search for all elements which look like the scheme above `<<<VALUE>>>` and create an array.

I found the following code but it doesn't work for me...

```
for /F "tokens=1-2 delims=<<<>>>-" %%a in (temp.csv) do (@echo %%a %%b)
```

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

I would like to use regular expressions now, but this doesn't work either...

```
for /f %%x in ("temp.csv") do (
  echo %%x | findstr /r "^<^<^<^(\.\?\*^)^>^>^>"
)
```

...any help? :)

kind regards,
markus

Answer (score 0):

I'm using now the simple tool [batchRex.exe](https://www.administrator.de/wissen/batchrex-regular-expressions-batch-nutzen-oder-extrahiert-bestimmten-text-212057.html) from administrator.de with an regular expression. I'm using the pattern `<<<(.*?)>>>` to get my values and save them to an .txt file. Afterwards I read line by line from this file into an array to work further on - just in case someone has the same problem ;-)

kind regards

markus